# How to input pure function to package?

Tags: function-construction, syntax, packages, functional-style, pure-function

I would like to input a pure function into a custom written package, but am running into a variety of errors. 
The package I have created is as follows:

```
BeginPackage["functions`"]

CosCoeff::usage="CosCoeff[m] returns cheb coeffs of order m of Cosine[2 Pi t]";

Begin["`Private`"]

ClearAll["Global`*"]

CosCoeff[m0_]:=
Module[{m=m0},
f[t]=Cos[2 Pi t];
Tn[t] = ChebyshevT[j, 2*t - 1]; 
wt[t] = 1/Sqrt[t - t^2]; 

p=Table[Chop[NIntegrate[f[t]*Tn[t]*wt[t], {t, 0, 1}]/(N[Pi]/2.0)], {j, 0, m-1}];
p[[1]]=p[[1]]/2;
p
]

End[]
EndPackage[]
```

This package as stated creates a table containing "m" shifted-Chebyshev coefficients for the function `Cos[2 Pi t]`. How can I input any function, say Sin[2 Pi t], instead of writing a different module for every function I need to use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can pass a function (or for that matter, anything!) as an argument to another function and you'll need to modify your code accordingly. See this example:

```
ChebyCoeff[func_, m0_] := Module[{m = m0},
    f[t] = func[2 Pi t];
    Tn[t] = ChebyshevT[j, 2*t - 1];
    wt[t] = 1/Sqrt[t - t^2];
    p = Table[Chop[NIntegrate[f[t]*Tn[t]*wt[t], {t, 0, 1}]/(N[Pi]/2.0)], {j, 0, m - 1}];
    p[[1]] = p[[1]]/2;
    p
]
```

Now `ChebyCoeff[Cos, 3]` will give the same result as your `CosCoeff[3]`.

Comment: Excellent! That's a step in the right direction. Now, is it possible to pass an entire function along with its argument/s? Say I want to evaluate 'f[t]=Sin[t]', 'Cos[Pi t]Sin[0.5 t]', 't+t^3', etc?

Comment: @gKirkland Sure. Change the line to `f[t] = func[t];` and then pass a pure function such as `Cos[Pi #]Sin[0.5 #]&` or `# + #^3&` to your function.